# Чем заменить YMKIndoor, удаленный в версии 4.2.0?

Tags: yandexmapkit, mapkit

В YandexMapKit в версии 4.2.0 был выпилен YMKIndoorPlan и все, что с ним связано. YMKIndoor был нужен для работы с этажами внутри зданий.

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть ли альтернатива в версии 4.2.0 YandexMapKit или данная фича ушла навсегда?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Вообще логично задавать вопрос сразу в поддержку Яндекса - ошибка у них какая или теперь просто не будут отдавать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Насколько удалось узнать, Яндекс действительно закрыл **Indoor**. Быть может позднее предложат, чем заменить, но планов они никогда не раскрывают, потому ждать не стоит.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! А откуда узнал если не секрет?

Comment: Так в поддержку и обратился, как рекомендовал.